# I will not stress about it or i wouldn't stress about it

Tags: meaning

Whats difference in this 
I won't interfere or i wouldn't interfere
Is there any difference

Answer (score 1):

"I will/I won't" expresses a definite intention on the part of the speaker as to what they are going to do themselves.

"I would/I wouldn't" can sometimes be a tentative statement of what the speaker might do. But it is much more commonly about what the hearer should or shouldn't do: advice, or a warning. It is part of the idiom "If I were you, I would(n't)...", but the first half is very often left out.

So "I won't interfere" is telling you what the speaker is not going to do.

"I wouldn't interfere" might in context be telling you about what the speaker would not do in some hypothetical circumstance. But it's much more likely to mean "I advise you not to interfere".

Comment: "I wouldn't interfere (if I were you)"  - the hypothetical is often omitted in casual speech when giving advice